# React - Slow state setting for dynamic rendered semantic UI dropdown component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and playing around with Semantic UI to improve my skills. However, I am having some trouble with setting initial state and laggy state updates on dropdown change. I'm using the Semantic UI table component with an integrated dropdown following an example from the Semantic Docs [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-remote). Essentially I want to render table rows dynamically based on the number of products from a JSON array with each row having its own dropdown element pre-filled with a color from the JSON array . On dropdown change I want the specific index to update its state for the dropdown.

```js
class DropdownExampleSelection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentValues: {}
    };
  }

  handleDropdownChange = (index, e, { value }) => {
    this.setState(({ currentValues }) => {
      currentValues[index] = value;
      return currentValues;
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { currentValues } = this.state;
    return (
      <Table celled padded>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell singleLine>Product</Table.HeaderCell>
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>
        <Table.Body>
          {entries.map((entry, index) => {
            return (
              <Table.Row key={entry._id}>
                <Table.Cell>
                  <Dropdown
                    placeholder="Select Color"
                    selection
                    options={colorOptions}
                    value={currentValues[index]}
                    onChange={this.handleDropdownChange.bind(this, index)}
                  />
                </Table.Cell>
              </Table.Row>
            );
          })}
        </Table.Body>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}

export default DropdownExampleSelection;
```

[See full code on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-vw9z6?fontsize=14)

**There are two issues I am having:**


**1.** I am not sure the correct way to set the initial state for each dropdown which should be the "color" from each product pre-populated as a dropdown value. See "entrylist.json" file in codesandbox above for the array

```
{
    "_id": 21,
    "title": "Product 21",
    "color": "red"
  }
```

**2.** The version in the above code sandbox updates the state at at a particular index, but the UI lags substantially when doing so. There are a good amount of products, but I think this is an issue somewhere in my code because when I use the default dropdown component from Semantic (with no custom state setup) [codesandbox example here](https://rhh0o.csb.app/) it does not lag and has the same amount of entries. Appreciate any guidance on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still look for to improve the performance of this. I have some suggestions.

@depish already said, you have too many Dropdown components and each one is rerendered, even if only 1 dropdown is changed. From this point we come to a question how can we render only Dropdown whose value has been changed?

In order to do that, you need to separate code below

```
        return (
          <Table.Row key={entry._id}>
            <Table.Cell>
              <Dropdown
                placeholder="Select Color"
                selection
                options={colorOptions}
                value={currentValues[index]}
                onChange={this.handleDropdownChange.bind(this, index)}
              />
            </Table.Cell>
          </Table.Row>
        );
```

to an outside React.PureComponent, and pass all the parameters which it needs (value, handleDropdownChange). Since PureComponent is rerendered only when there is a different props coming from parent, or state change.

It should solve your issue with getting all 150 dropdowns rendered

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

u can replace your constructor function with this one (let me know your progress)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.initalstate= entries.map((entry, index) => {
      return entry.color
    })
    this.state = {
      currentValues: {...this.initalstate}
    };

  }
```

Comment: that worked great for pre-filling the values, thank you! For the second part of the question.. any idea why the UI is laggy when switching values? Are there unnecessary renders going on? here is the example with your pre-filling working but still laggy https://vw9z6.csb.app/

Comment: https://vw9z6.csb.app/ (This has no pre-filling. I think you send my your earlier code output)

Comment: try this one https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example3-iuthp?fontsize=14

Comment: hlo mattylight10, since you update single dropdown that changes your state and this causes your render function to rendered again which inturn has to load your entire 150 dropdowns and only you view ur changed state in you current dropdown. (for demo ..if you had just worked with few dropdowns......your code works fast like this..https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example3-i1prt) .So it is not your code that is making slow.

Comment: got it. Thanks again for your help